# Limiting only specific emails to logIn with Gmail Oauth

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

I was wondering if I could just simply do the following to limit logins, but I seem to run into a problem where the page just reloads constatly once I log in once.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

    //list the emails that can login to the website using Gmail OAuth
    if (profile.getEmail() == "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com") {
        window.location.href = "./index.html"
    } else {
        let done = confirm("You don't have permission to access this.")
        if (done) {
            window.location.href = "https://www.HOMEPAGEco.uk/"
        } else {
            alert("Please try again.")
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: so you're already on index.html then, no need to do anything if they are in the whitelist, right?

Comment: @DanOswalt Yeah well once it gets to index it should just stop not need to do anything else yeah other than stay logged in. But at the moment it is constantly running the function I think.

Answer (score 0):

The line `window.location.href = "./index.html"` will always reload the page; if you want no action to be taken when they are in the whitelist, just check if they are NOT in the list.

```
if (profile.getEmail() !== "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com") {
    let done = confirm("You don't have permission to access this.")
    if (done) {
        window.location.href = "https://www.HOMEPAGEco.uk/"
    } else {
        alert("Please try again.")
    }
}
```